# Why do I get foreign key mismatch?

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

I can't figure out why I get a foreign key mismatch with the sqlite below:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;

CREATE TABLE a (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE b (
    a_id INT NOT NULL,
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (a_id, id),
    FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES a(id));

CREATE TABLE c (
    b_id INT NOT NULL,
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (b_id, id),
    FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES b(id));

insert into a VALUES (1);
insert into b VALUES (1, 2);
insert into c VALUES (2, 3);
```

The last line causes:

```
Error: foreign key mismatch - "c" referencing "b"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to reference the entire primary key of table b, not just one attribute of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of `b` is:

```
CREATE TABLE b (
    a_id INT NOT NULL,
    id INT NOT NULL,
    **PRIMARY KEY (a_id, id),**
    FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES a(id)
);
```

You have defined a *composite* primary key.  That is, the primary key has more than one column in it.  Any reference needs to use all the keys that are defined.  So you need an `a_id` for the reference:

```
CREATE TABLE c (
    b_id INT NOT NULL,
    id INT NOT NULL,
    a_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (b_id, id),
    FOREIGN KEY (a_id, b_id) REFERENCES b(a_id, id)
);
```

This is one of the reasons why I find composite primary keys to be cumbersome.  You can define a *synthetic* primary key for any table -- basically, an auto-incremented column.  This is then suitable for a foreign key reference.

Answer (score 1):

A composite primary key is a primary key consisting of more than one column.
in table `b` you have composite primary key which is `b_id, id` so you have to use both.You can learn about composite primary key with example: https://beginnersbook.com/2015/04/composite-key-in-dbms/

```
CREATE TABLE c (
    b_id INT NOT NULL,
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (b_id, id),
    FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES b(a_id, id))
```

Answer (score 1):

b table's PK is `a_id` + `id` so your c table's FK has to be referenced not only to `b(id)` but also to `b(a_id)`.
I can suggest you to avoid using of composite primary keys in tables.